# Script to spell check multiple documents and report results

Tags: python

I teach a class in which students write short, weekly reactions to an assigned reading. Assignments are graded based on simple rules, one of them being perfect spelling. Perfect spelling is a simple way to evaluate their work in a class where I am interested in spending time reading submissions for content.

I want to write a script that takes all student submissions and one by one checks whether spelling is perfect or not. Problem is, I have no idea how best to do this. One thought I had was to write a Python script that takes each assignment and runs it through Microsoft Word and collects the number of misspelled words. But is such a thing even possible?

Comment: Microsoft word is definitely not the way to go. There are a lot of spellchecker apis that will link very well with python, making your job much easier. I think the nltk has a spell checker builtin but if I remember correctly, [PyEnchant](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/) is a really good one.

Comment: How are the student's answers stored? Are you asking them to type them on a website or are they to write an answer on a piece of a paper and you enter the answers into the script? Are you going to give the script the actual correct answer or are you expecting the script to guess the correct answer. More info please.

Comment: @MooingRawr right now submissions are in .docx format, but based on the comments that will change. Whatever the format I want to keep all submissions in a folder and then feed the folder to the script. The program will then cycle through each submission and report the misspellings. I hoped to exploit an existing spellchecker rather than build my own

Comment: As a thought, just make them use notepad and save it as a .txt files. Since they are really easy to parse and read, you can use any of the spell checker down below. Should be simple. if you picked a spell checker and tried it and still run into issues, update your question.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply. Text files definitely an option. Will consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download a spell checking library like [PyEnchant](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/) using pip etc, the task is greatly simplified.

Here is a sample piece of code I just wrote up that you can use as a template:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import enchant

THRESHOLD = 1   # harsh

def numIncorrect(words_in_file):
    """
    @param words_in_file - an iterable of words in the current students submission.
    @return - the number of misspelled words in this submission.
    """  
    word_dict = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    count = 0
    for word in file:
        if not word_dict.check(word): count +=1
    return count;


def main():
    for filename in os.listdir('.'):    # assuming student submissions are in current directory. You can change this depending on how the files are stored (if they are online you could download them etc.)
        # ... Process filename i.e get student name out and open file, create a list with all its words (one liner) 
        if numIncorrect(words_in_file) > THRESHOLD:
            # ... mark this student for a deduction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: very interesting. Does it matter what format the submission is?

Comment: @invictus As I have written it here, the function numIncorrect takes a list (or any iterable) of words in one students submission.  So you would have to process whatever format the submission is to get a list of words first. This is not a difficult task at all but, If you clarify what kind of format you have the submissions in, I could be more specific. An ideal format would be a folder with txt files for each student submission where the filename contains the students name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the Microsoft Word route is possible, but you could use an API, such as [this.](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-spell-check-api)

Here is a Javascript example they have on their documentation website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSSample</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
        "text": "Bill Gatas",
        "mode": "{string}",
        "preContextText": "{string}",
        "postContextText": "{string}",
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{subscription key}");
        },
        type: "GET",
        // Request body
        data: "{body}",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are 2 Python examples:

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
# Request headers
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
# Request parameters
'text': 'Bill Gatas',
'mode': '{string}',
'preContextText': '{string}',
'postContextText': '{string}',
})

try:
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
conn.request("GET", "/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)
conn.close()
except Exception as e:
print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

####################################

########### Python 3.2 #############
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
# Request headers
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
# Request parameters
'text': 'Bill Gatas',
'mode': '{string}',
'preContextText': '{string}',
'postContextText': '{string}',
})

try:
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
conn.request("GET", "/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)
conn.close()
except Exception as e:
print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

####################################
```

Comment: Can you explain how these examples work?

Comment: Sure, are you interested in the javascript or python?

Comment: Def interested in the python version.

Comment: Ok so you get a subscription key when you sign up (free), and put that in {subscription key}. Then you put your parameters in the header, such as the text that you are checking and the context that it is in. Then you make a GET request and the api responds.